# Unknown logo on FGS25N120ANTD IGBTs. Which semiconductor manufacturer is this?

Tags: identification, semiconductors, igbt, manufacturing

I bought 5 FGS25N120ANTD IGBTs from my local vendor a while back.

I was unable to identify the manufacturer, based on the logo.

Can somebody help me out?

[image: Manufacturer logo on the IGBT]

[image: This is the IGBT I bought]

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you about the manufacturer?

Comment: I only find data sheets from fairchild, but the symbol on the igbt is not fairchild's

Comment: So, on what basis did you buy the chips in the first place?

Comment: @Andyaka I can imagine when buying from a local small store that you don't pick the brand? There is a local store near my place of work that sells components, but if you want say a 1N4001, they could give you any of the major brands, just whatever they have in stock then.

Comment: @JorenVaes you might but I wouldn't.

Comment: In 41 billion images, [no match](https://tineye.com/search/7c3658e2b4c126f0564136dacdee78226631c689?page=1).

Comment: I asked the vendor for fga25n120antd and he gave me this igbt. The part name is clearly specified, however I expected to see a Fairchild logo instead I saw this. It was a mystery logo one which I had never seen before.

Comment: Fairchild don't exist any more  - they were bought by ON semi and possibly the IGBT branch was resold like they did with some TVSs.

Comment: There are many second sources of these things in Asia with various brands or no brand at all. You can assume the part is purported to match Fairchild's performance numbers. Whether it does or not is another matter, but it's likely close.